# Replacing a variable with function(variable)

Tags: javascript, function, variable-assignment

Is there a shortcut for

```
myVar = myFunction(myVar);
```

?

Similar to `myVar+=2;` instead of `myVar=myVar+2;`

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on, what transformation, does the ``function`` ``myFunction`` do?

Comment: Get the concepts clearly. `myVar = myFunction(myVar);` means assigning value to `myvar` after function `returns` the value. What you want to do actually?

Comment: No, there is no such shortcut. If you want to mutate objects though, you might use a method call for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, no such expression exists. If we examine [ECMAScript 5 section 11.13](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13), we see that there are *simple* assignments (`=`) and *compound* assignments (`op=`). The compound assignment operators are listed exhaustively in the spec:

```
*=  /=  %=  +=  -=  <<=  >>=  >>>=  &=  ^=  |=
```

None of these operators apply a named function.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's no specific operator, however nothing prevents you from doing something similar using an object as a variable context.

```
function VarContext() {}

VarContext.prototype.someFunction = function (member) {
    //could be any kind of processing
    this[member] += 1;
};

var ctx = new VarContext();

ctx.test = 1;
ctx.someFunction('test');
ctx.test; //2
```

Functions can be bound to the object as well.

```
someFunction = ctx.someFunction.bind(ctx);
```

Then you can just write:

```
someFunction('test');
```